# Removing facets inside another object when they intersect (pictures included)

Tags: python, modifiers

I'm looking to remove the faces from inside one object where another object intersects it. 
[image: Box in a box]

[image: Just making it clear the box extends into the other box]

So, what I'm looking to remove would be the plane inside the small box from the big box.  This is just an example, so these objects will be complex.  I can't find a boolean that will do this for me in Blender.  My friend who has Maya says Boolean Union using Normals instead of faces does exactly this, but with Blender's Union it drops the bottom of the small box (and the plane inside the small box).  I would love to be able to do this programmatically as well and without intersecting faces as this will be something that will need to be done a lot in a step of a computational engineering test bed, but I'll try not to get too greedy here.  Please let me know if I am unclear on anything.

Answer (score 1):

[image]For anyone trying to do the same thing as I am here is my hacky way of solving it.  I first did a difference as quiliup suggested, and then did a union with the original small cube, and finally removed duplicates.  If anyone knows a more concise way to do this though I'd be happy to approve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand if  you want to connect both of those objects. If so then boolean works. Just add boolean on one obj and then use Union and select the other mesh.

[image]

then just hit apply and your mesh should be  cut. But both of them will be combined into one mesh with bad topology.

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear on what I was wanting.  I want the facets inside the small box to be gone, but I still want the bottom of the small box.  In a perfect world I want a joined mesh where there are no intersecting faces and the facets inside the small box from the large box are deleted.  As you see it is killing the bottom of the small box. Thank you btw for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I also have problems understanding. Maybe this is what you want:
The boolean difference modifier applied to the bigger one. It keeps the bottom of your smaller cube (even if I forgot to show this in the gif).
[image]

Comment: What I'm looking for is a joined mesh where the plane inside the smaller box from the larger box is gone.  Like I said it would be great if it meshed it without intersecting faces, but one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

**follow the prints, follow the prints .. rsrs :)**

[image]

**Select boolean and apply difference**

[image]
[image]

**Select the larger box that will make the cut**

[image]

**Apply the boolean and it will be ready!**

[image]
[image]
[image]